# Flutter 2.0 The return type of getter 'xxxx' is 'dynamic' which isn't a subtype of the type 'List<dynamic>' of its setter 'xxxx'

Tags: flutter, flutter2.0

I'm recently migrate my code to flutter 2.0, but I'm getting this error:
error: The return type of getter 'tabbarcatinfo' is 'dynamic' which isn't a subtype of the type 'List' of its setter 'tabbarcatinfo'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
List _tabbarcatinfo = [];

class TabBarCategoriesInfo with  ChangeNotifier{
  static late List<String> name;

  get tabbarcatinfo {
    return _tabbarcatinfo;
  }

  set tabbarcatinfo(List Listita) {
    _tabbarcatinfo = Listita;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addData(List Listita) {
    _tabbarcatinfo.add(Listita);
    //notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the runtime type of Listita?

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud, the type of Listita: List<dynamic> Listita. about the other answer "you shouldn't use List with <>", i don't understand, I'm not using it, but I tried too

Comment: Sorry it should be without <>, my bad.

Comment: I think you must specify the type of the list when you configured it

Comment: @RafaelZablah I have added an answer check it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have not properly defined types in your code.

Use it like this.

```
List<String> _tabbarcatinfo = [];

class TabBarCategoriesInfo with ChangeNotifier {
  static late List<String> name;

  List<String> get tabbarcatinfo {
    return _tabbarcatinfo;
  }

  set tabbarcatinfo(List<String> Listita) {
    _tabbarcatinfo = Listita;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addData(String item) {
    _tabbarcatinfo.add(item);
    //notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment if you have any particular doubt about a line and I will elaborate by answer to explain it.

Comment: thank you Nisanth for your answer!!, that's work perfectly! best regards!

Comment: glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
get tabbarcatinfo {
  return [..._tabbarcatinfo] as List<dynamic>;
}
```

Edit: Add the cast `List<dynamic>` in return statement.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but no lucky :(

Comment: thank you again, but with the edited answer not lucky again

Answer (score 0):

Need set a type before get.

List get tabbarcatinfo

And anothrw question, your list doesn't have a type? If I'm not mistaken it must have any type.

Comment: thank you for your answer too, I tried too, but no lucky!

Comment: Hm.. Your _tabbarcatinfo list is not in the class.it is not a mistake?

Comment: You're are right!, it must be in the class, my mistake, regards Graaggas